# How close am I to achieve my goal and what kind of techniques do I need to learn and apply to do that?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am creating a database-driven website using the Django framework. The website is the front-end for a database that contains different Physics' questions and answers. The purpose of the database is to organize these questions according to topic and retrieve them on the website according to input made by the user.

The first input is a selection form with 16 topics.
The second input is a selection form with two types of questions (problem solving and multiple choices).
The third input is radio checkboxes to have the questions with answers or without answers.
The forth input is a selection form with different numbers 10 to 50 (10 steps between each) to determine the number of questions wanted.

I have already created the website and the database. What is causing me a problem is the forms and model forms. I have been reading and summarizing the Django Documentation to understand the functionality of Django.

I would like to have the opinion of experts where I am in the process and what kind of sources I can read to achieve my goal.

I have been trying different sources but because I haven't been focusing on learning but focusing on building the project, I have wasted a lot of time, that is why I have been analysing the Django Documentation in a more proper way.

This is my `models.py` where I have created four `classes` and linked them together. Please tell me if this model achieves my goal.

```
    from django.db import models
    from home.choices import *

    # Create your models here.

    class Topic(models.Model):
        topic_name              = models.IntegerField(
                        choices = question_topic_name_choices, default = 1)
        def __unicode(self):
            return u'%s' % self.topic_name

    class Image (models.Model):
        image_file              = models.ImageField()

        def __unicode(self):
            return u'%s' % self.image_file

    class Question(models.Model):
        questions_type          = models. IntegerField(
                        choices = questions_type_choices, default = 1)
        question_topic          = models.ForeignKey(    'Topic',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        blank=True,
                                        null=True)
        question_description    = models.TextField()
        question_answer         = models.ForeignKey(    'Answer',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        blank=True,
                                        null=True)
        question_image          = models.ForeignKey(    'Image',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        blank=True,
                                        null=True)

        def __unicode(self):
            return u'%s' % self.question_description

    class Answer(models.Model):
        answer_description      = models.TextField()
        answer_image            = models.ForeignKey(    'Image',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        blank=True,
                                        null=True)

        def __unicode(self):
            return u'%s' % self.answer_description
```

This is my `forms.py` and I am aware that it is not written probably and fully which is why I am asking for help, what do I need to read and learn to make it what I want.

```
    from django import forms
    from betterforms.multiform import MultiModelForm
    from .models import Topic, Image, Question, Answer

    class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
        topic_name      =   forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                        queryset    =   Topic.objects.all(),
                        widget      =   forms.SelectMultiple(
                        attrs       =   {'class': ''}
                        ))
        class Meta:
            model   =   Topic
            fields  =   ['topic_name',]

    class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
        question_type    =   forms.ModelChoiceField(
                        queryset    =   Topic.objects.all(),
                        widget      =   forms.Select(
                        attrs       =   {'class': ''}
                        ))
        class Meta:
            model   =   Question
            fields  =   ['questions_type',]
    class QuizMultiForm(MultiModelForm):
        form_classes    =   {
                    'topics'    :   TopicForm,
                    'questions' :   QuestionForm
        }
        def __str__(self, args, kwargs):
            return '%s %s' %(self.topic_name)
```

This is my `views.py` and the biggest problem is here, I have understood how views work but I don't know how to apply some of the rules, basically Python rules.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from home.models import Topic, Image, Question, Answer
from home.forms import QuizMultiForm

class QuizView(CreateView):
    form_classes    =   QuizMultiForm
    template_name   =   'index.html'
    def form_valid(self, form_classes):
        return super().form_valid(form_classes)
```

This is my `urls.py` and I am not sure whther I have a problem here.

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include
    from home.views import QuizView
    from ask.views import ask_page_view as ask_page_url
    from download.views import download_view as download_url

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('ask/', ask_page_url, name = 'ask_page'),
        path('home/', QuizView.as_view(), name = 'home_page'),
        path('download/', download_url, name = 'download_page'),
    ]
```

This is an image that I have taken from my website but this one is only built using HTML and CSS whcih means it is not functional

[image]

Comment: In Python, it is good practice to declare variables like: `form_classes = QuizMultiForm` rather than your declarations above... notice the whitespace. Please see for more: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements

Comment: You're definitely on the right lines, although I think you're running before you can walk. Your complex Form objects are quite ambitious for a first ever working form. Try creating the simplest possible form first, with one input, and see if you can link it to the front end to save data, then build up from there. This [tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/) on forms is a good entry point (also the official Django tutorial from the beginning, as it introduces forms quite late on). Also learning more general Python will help, e.g. "__unicode" is not valid syntax.